# relationship between ${}_1F_1(a,1,x)$ and ${}_1F_1(b,1/2,x)$

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to simplify ${}_1F_1(b,1/2,x)$ to see if I can bring it to the form ${}_1F_1(a,1,x)$ for some $a$. I have tried to expand the series representation as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{}_1F_1 \left(b,\frac12,x\right) & = \frac 1{\Gamma(b)} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(b+k)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)} \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
& = \frac1{\Gamma(b)\sqrt\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(b+k)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma\left(2k+1\right)} \frac{(4x)^k}{k!}\\
& = \frac1{\Gamma(b)\sqrt\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(b+k)}{\Gamma\left(2k+1\right)} (4x)^k\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where I use
\begin{equation}
\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right) = \frac{(2k)!}{4^k k!}\sqrt\pi,
\end{equation}
in the above.
However, the previous derivation is not what I was trying to get. Is there a relationship (perhaps in the asymptote) that I can use here? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bring it to the form ${}_1F_1(a,1,x)$"?

Comment: Sorry, I am wondering if it is possible to write ${}_1F_1(b,\frac12,x)$ in terms of a confluent hypergeometric distribution that has 1 in the second argument.